# Remove all databases from my application except the specified database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to remove all other databases and shared pref from my application except the one I am specifying by providing name, say XYZ.

I want to keep only newly created database in my application and delete older databases with whatever names. So i know only my database name (the one i want to keep in application) and delete other databases (do not have names of databases those i want to delete).

Comment: talking about table or database ?

Comment: i want to delete database without knowing name of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this. But hope this may help you.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < databaseList().length; i++) {
                    String db_name = databaseList()[i];
                    deleteDatabase(db_name);
                }
```

Comment: how you will get databaseList()? thats what i want, list of dbs

Comment: Thanks @Nandha Kumar. databaseList() helped me to get the list of all DB. I just need to call getApplicationContext().databaseList();